# org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchWindowException: Unable to get browser while trying to open Internet Explorer 11 through Selenium and IEDriverServer

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, internet-explorer-11, selenium-iedriver

I'm unable to launch Internet Explorer browser with the selenium webdriver. Facing the below error, can anyone please help

Error occured:

```
Started InternetExplorerDriver server (32-bit)
3.14.0.0
Listening on port 45640
Only local connections are allowed
Aug 06, 2019 3:32:27 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: W3C
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchWindowException: Unable to get browser
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:48'
System info: host: 'A13540', ip: '10.40.75.65', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_60'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, browserName: internet explorer, browserVersion: 11, javascriptEnabled: true, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: WINDOWS, platformName: WINDOWS, proxy: Proxy(), se:ieOptions: {browserAttachTimeout: 0, elementScrollBehavior: 0, enablePersistentHover: true, ie.browserCommandLineSwitches: , ie.ensureCleanSession: false, ie.fileUploadDialogTimeout: 3000, ie.forceCreateProcessApi: false, ignoreProtectedModeSettings: false, ignoreZoomSetting: false, initialBrowserUrl: http://localhost:45640/, nativeEvents: true, requireWindowFocus: false}, setWindowRect: true, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}}
Session ID: ddba15a7-0a39-45cb-89d5-e6023ff636da
```

Answer (score 1):

This error message...

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchWindowException: Unable to get browser
```

...implies that the **IEDriverServer** was unable to initiate/spawn a new **WebBrowsing Session** i.e. **InternetExplorer Browser** session.

Your main issue is the **incompatibility** between the version of the binaries you are using as follows:

- Your *Selenium Client* version is *3.141.59*.
- Your *InternetExplorerDriver* version *3.14.0.0*.
- Your *JDK version* is **1.8.0_60** which is pretty ancient.

So there is a clear mismatch between the *Selenium Client v3.141.59*, *InternetExplorerDriver v3.14.0.0* and *JDK v8u60*. As per *best practices* as *Selenium Client* and *InternetExplorerDriver* are released in sync and you must use both the binaries from the same release.

---

### Solution

- Upgrade *JDK* to  current levels [JDK 8u212](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html).
- Upgrade *IEDriverServer* to  current [IEDriverServer v3.141.59](http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=3.141/) level.
- *Clean* your *Project Workspace* through your *IDE* and *Rebuild* your project with required dependencies only.
- Execute your `@Test`.

Answer (score 0):

Few points to check:
1. Check for security settings. Enable protected mode for all Options "Internet, Local Internet, Trusted Sites, Restricted sites" must not be selected. 
2. Check for iedriverserver.exe(for IE 11 3.14) version compatibility.

Thanks and regards,
Sandeep Jaju